# Create basic app - MEAN

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm new to Node.js and Express as well. I would like to create a basic AngularJS application but I don't know where to start. Here is the file organisation I would like to achieve :

```
- public
----- app
---------- components
----------------- component0
----------------------- c0controller.js
----------------------- c0.html
----------------------- c0Service.js
----------------- component1
----------------------- c1controller.js
----------------------- c1.html
----------------------- c1Service.js
---------- assets [...]
----- index.html
----- app.js
----- module.js
- node_modules [...]
- server.js
- route.js
```

First thing, is it possible to do that ?

Basically, the `index.html` file is where I define the `ui-view` of my angular application.

My main problem is that I can't find out how to setup my node server in `server.js`... Here is what I have but to be honest I don't understand every lines...

```
// set up ========================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                     // mongoose for mongodb
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)
var routes = require('./routes.js');

// configuration =================

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');     // connect to mongoDB database

app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/app');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));                 // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('*', routes.index);

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

And in `routes.js` I export the following method :

```
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
};
```

I already installer `ejs` but I'm not sure what to do with it... I'm a little bit lost so any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Have you looked at seeds? Like: https://github.com/meanie/express-seed

Comment: I'll give it a go tomorrow thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a short explanation of each line....

The following are libraries you required to use in your project ...

```
// set up ========================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                     // mongoose for mongodb
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)
```

The routes variable is set to the imported/required object from within the routes.js file of your app. There likely will be a modules.export object that is assigned a routes object in the routes.js file which is to be exported into the other parts of your app.

```
var routes = require('./routes.js');
```

This is where you connect to your db. You are using the mongoose library to help you create schemas for your models. The string inside the connect method of mongoose is the location of your database ('test'). You need to make sure you are running mongodb before you try to serve the app.

```
// configuration =================    
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');     // connect to mongoDB database
```

This where you set views of your application to the app directory inside the public directory. Inside app, you will be able to create your html files.

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/app');
```

Here you are stating your view engine will be plain html.

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

You are telling express all your static files such as images will be inside the /public directory.

```
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));                 
//set the 
static files location /public/img will be /img for users
```

The following are middleware you will need to aid you in your application development. Morgans is self evident as it has a comment, bodyParser is critical for parsing the body of your response and request http objects...

```
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());
```

This are your routes. Basically when you hit the route '/', whatever is inside routes.index gets executed...

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('*', routes.index);
```

Below you are specifying port 8080 as the port where your app will listen to incoming requests.

```
// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for every details! I understood almost everything I think but I'm not sure about the views part... For now when I browse localhost:8080 I'm automatically redirected to localhost:8080/#/home. It means the index.html file is found and the code inside app.js (where I define angular routes) is executed... But home.html is not rendered... Actually it's not even found as long as I have a 500 error code... What do I need to render the templateUrl I want to use? Thanks for your time!

Comment: #/home is defined in your angular app, as angular can be configured to use client side routing. Your express app is serverside rendering.

You'll need to update the angular code